# how to change the footer font color in datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I included the smooth theme from the Jquery [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller), i have set the pagination as numbers, But the color of these are black, which looks odd, how can i change to white

Here how the image looks [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you change the color by styling `#footer { color: #fff }` for example, you will not change a link colors ... so if the pagination consist of `<a>`'s, the color can be changed only when a style is applied on the `<a>` , not on parent elements, so you should do it something like :

```
#footer a { color: #fff }
```

If you give some more code I will have more precise answer, cause I am not sure I understand you correct.

Comment: i have downloaded the smooth theme from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller. also i m using the datatables css, even in his sample also he is getting blue only. http://datatables.net/styling/themes/start.. Here is what the css i'm using http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css